# Clone a custom table in Azure Analytics

Tags: azure, kql, azure-analysis-services, azure-analytics

I have a table in Azure Analytics called TestTable_CL, which has a lot of data there.

I want to clone this table to another one, but only the schema, not the data.

How is this possible?

I have tried to run multiple kusto queries in the Query Editor but not successful...

One of them is for example this:

```
.create table TestTableCopy_CL (schemaof(TestTable_CL))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `.create table based-on` command to clone a  table without data.

**Syntax:**

```
.create table <new_table_name> based-on <otherTable>
```

I reproduced this with a sample table in Kusto database.

- Created a table named Person and inserted data in that.

[image]

- Below Query is written to create a new table `person_cloned_table`

```
.create table person_cloned_table based-on Person
```

[image]

- When new table is queried for data, it has zero row with same schema as table `Person`

[image]

**Reference:** [.create table based-on - Azure Data Explorer | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/create-table-based-on-command)

Comment: Hi @Aswin, Thanks for the answer. I think what you provided is only possible in https://dataexplorer.azure.com/. I need to do it for a Custom table in Azure Analytics Workspace which has that Query Editor....